# How to change used Dart version in Android Studio?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am trying to run this command in terminal

```
flutter pub run intl_translation:extract_to_arb --output-dir=lib/i18n lib/i18n/app_localization.dart
```

and I get this error

```
Dart 2.15.1 is incompatible with your dependencies' SDK constraints. Please run "flutter pub get" again.
pub finished with exit code 65
```

And I noticed that the used Dart version is 2.15.1 and not version 2.10.5 which is specified in the Android Studio project settings

[image: Screenshot of the Android Studio project settings and dart version specified in it]

How would I change the actually used Dart version to be able to run the intl_translation command ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the version you want from this link. https://dart.dev/get-dart/archive

Comment: and after that ? how would I change the actually used dart version ? I already have both dart versions downloaded on my device

Comment: You can just add to "Dart SDK Path" the SDK folder path you want.

Answer (score 0):

From SDK manager in android studio you can change the flutter SDK and dart SDK to the path of the versions you want to use.
And then restart IDE